# Odoo windows all in one: can't install postgreSQL after desinstalled it

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I installed "odoo_9.0c.latest"  ..  then uninstall all installed programs (postgresql, server)..
when I tried to reinstall it .. I had an error message at the end ...
" A service (PostgreSQL_For_Odoo) already exists. Please specify another name. "
Screenshot : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/685565Screenshot23.png

Comment: Delete postgresql service from the registry,see if its gone from the service list and check for any remaining traces of it in C drive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technical note: after investigation it seems that the PostgreSQL 9.x uninstaller does not cleanup the registry keys in the same fashion as the 8.3 did, and the following keys remain after a complete uninstall:

```
HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL +- HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL\Installations +- HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL\Services
```

Currently our installer just checks for the presence of the HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL entry, but it could still be there even if no PostgreSQL installation remains. So when it is present we should verify that at least one entry exists under HKLM\Software\PostgreSQL\Installations. The 8.3 installer apparently removed the PostgreSQL entry altogether, so that should work everywhere.

PS: when manually using regedit on a x64 system these keys will be found under HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node, which is the "reflection key" that is mapped to HKLM\Software for 32bits processes running on a 64bits machine. It can be ignored for all purposes except when manually viewing/editing the registry. The installer will run as 32bits so it will find them in the normal location.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution that worked for me was:

Open a cmd terminal and type:

```
services.msc
```

it will open a window showing all the services. Next, make sure you have a service called: PostgreSQL_For_Odoo

if it exists, Open another CMD windows as administrator and type:

```
sc delete "PostgreSQL_For_Odoo"
```

This command will delete the PostgreSQL_For_Odoo servce.

I hope it works for you!